# Machine learning through R/Python in the Netezza server

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, netezza

Is it possible to run machine learning through R (RStudio) or Python in a Netezza server? More specifically, can I train models and make predictions using the Netezza server? Has anybody been able to install TensorFlow, Keras or Pytorch in the Netezza server for these ML tasks?

I appreciate any feedback whether this is feasible or not.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to install R and To my knowledge all kinds of R-packages can be installed. Some of the code will only run on the HOST but all the basics (like Apply and filtering) runs on all the SPU’s

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Lars. Have you actually installed R packages (i.e.: caret, keras, etc) in the NZ server and train a model in the server? I still find it very unclear whether this is feasible or not. I have not been able to find any examples from IBM. I have heard from people that even running R code in the server requires some sort of C++ compilation, but I am also not sure about that.

Comment: I’m not using R myself on Netezza, but You Will have to bring your local friendly DBA into the loop and ask him to download & compile & indtall the packages after the initial R install has been completed